# Something's wrong with the makefile indentation? (Makefile:x: *** missing separator. Stop.)

Tags: makefile, kernel-module

I'm currently working on a research project, and we got to a point where we need to test execution times without cache memory enabled. I found a kernel module on https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/disabling-cpu-caches-936077/page2.html that enables and disables cache, but I just can't build it.

The makefile provided by "ulmo" is:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS = -m32
obj-m += disableCache.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

but everytime I run it, I get:

```
Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I have already tried to play with tabs and spaces (put 1 tab, 2 tabs, 4 spaces, 8 spaces, odd number of spaces), run the commands all alone in bash, and even replace `$(shell uname -r)` with my own linux version, but still get the same "syntax" error. I have little to no experience with Makefiles, so I really do not know why this is happening.

Comment: the `make` line (line 5 where the error is) must start with a <tab> character.  The error message indicates that it does not

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the output of `cat -T Makefile` (assuming your makefile *is* called `Makefile`).  It may be that your editor is replacing tabs with spaces.

Comment: Also, watch out for the possibility of one or more spaces preceding the first tab.  When it's looking for tab indentation, `make` considers only the very first character of the line.